# ClassCastException in multi-module project running on Quarkus (gradle)

Tags: quarkus

I seem the get weird classcast exceptions in multi-module project.
Here is an shortened overview of the project structure:

```
Project: dto-commons
    contains
        -> AuditingEntityObjectSelector (a normal java class)
        -> AbstractAuditingEntity (JPA @MappedSuperClass)

Project: model
    contains lots of JPA entities, which all extend AbstractAuditingEntity from the project 'dto-commons'
    depends on 
        -> dto-commons

Project: selectors
    contains
        -> SampleRequestSelector (a normal java class which extends AuditingEntityObjectSelector from the project 'dto-commons'
    depends on 
        -> model


Project:mainservices
    - model
    - selectors
    - dto-commons

Project:rest-api   --> This project is launched with quarkusDev (gradle)
    - mainservices
```

I've created a little testresource where I inject some services, an EntityManager etc.
Everything seems to be working, except that I get very weird ClassCastExceptions

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   com.geodesk.queryinfrastructure.selector.SampleRequestSelector cannot
>   be cast to class
>   com.geodesk.domain.queryinfrastructure.AuditingEntityObjectSelector

Some debugging shows me the following:

```
new SampleRequest() instanceof AbstractAuditingEntity --> true (which is correct)
new SampleRequestSelector() instanceof AuditingEntityObjectSelector --> false (which is NOT correct)
```

This is probably a classloading issue, but I can't figure out what is causing this.

```
SampleRequest.class.classLoader == AbstractAuditingEntity.class.classloader --> true 
SampleRequestSelector.class.classLoader == AuditingEntityObjectSelector.class.classloader --> false (don't know for sure, but I think that should be true)
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

(note that all projects do have an empty META-INF/beans.xml in their resources dir)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like another installment of our class loader issues. We are currently actively working on fixing them but it's not an easy subject.

I suppose you only have the issue with quarkusDev? Not when you execute the `-runner.jar`?

It would be helpful if you could try to put together a simple reproducer and open a GH issue so that we can be sure the current class loader work fixes this issue too.

Comment: I'll try setup a reproducer; give me a few days.

Comment: Create a runner jar doesn't seem to work since it gives duplicate meta-inf/beans.xml, but that's probably another issue...

Comment: You mean an uber jar? I'm talking about the standard -runner jar created when executing a standard build.

Comment: I'm using Gradle. running 'gradlew :services:test-api:quarkusBuild'  gives me java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: META-INF/beans.xml
De same for gradlew :services:test-api:build