# ClassCastException in Quarkus multi-module project

Tags: quarkus

My problem seems similar to [ClassCastException in multi-module project running on Quarkus (gradle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59523154/classcastexception-in-multi-module-project-running-on-quarkus-gradle).

I am using maven, though. I can confirm the problem do not occur when using the runner or in tests. I created a sample application to reproduce the issue in https://github.com/AmsterdamFilho/quarkus-poc.

If you run the application in dev mode and execute the endpoint using swagger-ui or curl you get the Exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class br.com.quarkus.poc.AnimalKindService_ClientProxy cannot be cast to class br.com.quarkus.poc.AnimalKindService (br.com.quarkus.poc.AnimalKindService_ClientProxy is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; br.com.quarkus.poc.AnimalKindService is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.runner.RuntimeClassLoader @7c6908d7)`

The Quarkus version is 1.1.1.

Any workaround would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a class loader issue. We have a brand new class loader design in master that will come to Quarkus 1.3 (so roughly in a month).

Could you test your issue is solved if you're using master?

You can either build it locally with `mvn clean install -DskipTests -DskipITs` then use `999-SNAPSHOT` as the version or we publish the snapshots here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/quarkus/ .

Note: you will need to use the `quarkus-bom` to make this test so change that in your pom if you're pointing to the `quarkus-universe-bom`.

Thanks for checking.

Comment: I built it locally from master. The issue is fixed. Thanks.